# How to order a given array in respect to another array considering it as substrings of data elements

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

How can I order a given array respectively to another array? Searching didn't find solution for this case. Briefly, an array that defines sorting order is like this (example):

```
$arrayorder = array("z", "q", "9", "1");
```

and an array I would like to sort using order defined by `$arrayorder` is like this:

```
$data = array("a1", "za", "19", "18", "qz", "qc", "qd", "zc", "zb", "u", "z9");
```

the output array should be:

```
$output = array ("z9", "za", "zb", "zc", "qc", "qd", "qz", "18", "19", "a1", "u");
```

In practice, `$data` array should be sorted based on order defined by `$arrayorder`, for example:

```
"zGray", "zBlue"
```

resulting order is:

```
"zBlue", "zGray"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the `usort` function allows you to define your own comparison function.  Although not elegant, you could do something like

```
usort ($data, function ($a, $b)
{
    $arrayorder = array("z", "q", "9", "1", "a", "u");
    $ea = array_search(substr($a,0,1), $arrayorder );
    $eb = array_search(substr($b,0,1), $arrayorder );
    if ($ea == $eb) {
        if ( $a == $b ) {
            return 0;
        }
        else {
            return ($a< $b) ? -1 : 1;
        }
    }
    return ($ea< $eb) ? -1 : 1;
});
```

It's important to have all of the possible first chars in the arrayorder, or change the code to set some default being a high number to push them to the end of the sort order.